# Как называется поисковик с ИИ?

Tags: поисковые-системы

Кажется, вопрос не совсем по тематике СО, но не знаю куда его ещё задать.

Слышал, появился недавно какой-то умный ИИ поисковик, по моему, название короткое, камелкейс из двух частей, начинается, вроде, на "c".

Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0?cb=1

Comment: Попробуйте спросить в чате https://chat.openai.com/chat :-)

Answer (score 1):

Это [ChatGPT](https://www.google.com/search?q=ChatGPT) разработанный OpenAI.